# Trigonometry (triangle)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In an acute triangle ABC, AB = 27, BC = 21, AC = 6. How to find sin(B) / sin(C) without using calculator? Is there any formula to calculate this? Pls help me. My teacher just taught me what is sin/cos/tan. He give us this question and a triangle with 3 lines on it (kinda like symmetrical line).

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Are you familiar with the Law of Sines?

Comment: No, My teacher didn't even teach it.

Comment: It's possible the teacher is trying to motivate the Law by having you discover it. Be that as it may ... Please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4417891/edit) to tell us what you *do* know, to help people advise you appropriately without using tools or techniques you haven't covered.

Comment: Note: $27=21+6$.  I would not call this an acute triangle.

Comment: Dk my teacher just give the numbers.

Comment: Try to construct this triangle accurately using compasses and you might spot the problem

Comment: This triangle is a straight line??